configure SSL for webserver on last stage of the network
I made a simple network with a webserver on the 8080 port (http-only).
As the diagram, I need to use http only on this webserver and configure SSL on the next stage, which is a Linux pc.
Please let me know if it is possible to configure SSL for my webserver on Linux PC (not on the webserver).
My network Diagram

yes, it is possible. What http server will be running on the "Linux PC"? Choose something that can do so called "reverse proxy"

Indeed - the Linux machine will be configured with a "reverse proxy" that does "TLS off-loading". Note that such a configuration implies that the network between your "web server"  and "Linux" hosts is fully trusted, as all communications between those systems will be in the clear text HTTP protocol. Modern thinking is that no network should be be considered trusted  and that you should always encrypt all traffic that you can encrypt and otherwise you're neglecting security.

What you are looking for is a reverse proxy. Nginx can do it, apache can do it, caddy can do it while obtaining Let’s Encrypt cert on the fly, you can even code one. I built one in go when I was learning: https://github.com/bestmethod/goproxy
Pick a solution. I would say caddy for simplicity. If not, nginx or apache with reverse proxy configured.
